# react-bootstrap-table: cannot set a glyphicon on a custom toolbar button

Tags: javascript, html, glyphicons, react-bootstrap-table

I am customizing the toolbar of a table, following this example: http://allenfang.github.io/react-bootstrap-table/custom.html#insertBtn

I can see my buttons, but not the icons that I set with btnGlyphicon.

The generated html is `<i class="fa glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></i>` Are both fa + glyphicon expected in the class ? I added font-awesome as a dependency, but I still cannot see the icon.

What am I missing?

Any help appreciated

```js
import React from 'react';

import {
 BootstrapTable, TableHeaderColumn, 
 ButtonGroup, Button, InsertButton
} from 'react-bootstrap-table';
import './../node_modules/react-bootstrap-table/dist/react-bootstrap-table-all.min.css';
import './../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';


createCustomButtonGroup(props) {
  return (
    <ButtonGroup className='my-custom-class' sizeClass='btn-group-md'>
   { props.exportCSVBtn }
   <InsertButton 
     btnText='Info'
     className='my-custom-class'
     btnGlyphicon='glyphicon-edit'
     onClick={ () => this.changeInfoFilter() }/>
   <InsertButton 
     btnText='Warning'
     className='my-custom-class'
     btnGlyphicon='glyphicon-edit'
     onClick={ () => this.changeWarningFilter() }/>
   <InsertButton
     btnText='Error'
     className='my-custom-class'
     btnGlyphicon='glyphicon-edit'
     onClick={ () => this.changeErrorFilter() }/>
   <InsertButton 
     btnText='Command'
     className='my-custom-class'
     btnGlyphicon='glyphicon-edit'
     onClick={ () => this.changeCommandFilter() }/>
    </ButtonGroup>
  );
 }
```

Comment: the problem seems to be with my bootstrap.min.css. If I replace by "https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" I can see icons. The one I use is more recent: 4.1.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently it is a known issue, glyphicons are not in bootstrap 4:
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/migration/